# Problem getting pairs in a 3D list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm working with list comprehension but I'm having a trouble working this out, so, I have a 3D list in which I'm trying to obtain pairs in the inner lists, I created a code, in which I can obtain pairs, but it's not exactly what I need, here is my code:

```
mylist = [[[3, 2, 4, 3], [3, 2, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [3, 1], [2, 1]]]

res = [[x[idx: idx+2] for i in mylist for x in i for idx in range(0, len(x) - 1)]]

print(res)

#res = [[[3, 2], [2, 4], [4, 3], [3, 2], [2, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [2, 1]]]
```

As you can see, I do get a 3D list with the pairs, but, it's not separated, its just a plain 3D list, I was expecting this:

```
#Output
res = [[[3, 2], [2, 4], [4, 3], [3, 2], [2, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [2, 1]]]
#                                                       ^
#                                              Here is the separation
```

I'm working on my list comprehension, but I can't see where is happening the problem, I believe there is something wrong with the bracket, but I been trying different combinations but nothing seems to work, so any help will be appreciated.

Also, maybe this is bit of a stretch, but there is some way I can eliminate some repeated inner list in the 3D list, I mean, using `res` to get:

```
newres = [[[3, 2], [2, 4], [4, 3], [2, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [2, 1]]]

#[3, 2], [2, 1] eliminated
```

If you can point me to the right direction that would be great, thank you so much!

Comment: *Why* should those separations be where you want them?

Comment: Yes, sorry, in mylist the last element in the inner list is [2,1] and the the new inner list starts in [1, 2] so there should be a separation between them, but my code was giving me together, just plain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[x[idx: idx+2] for x in i for idx in range(0, len(x) - 1)] for i in mylist ]
```

Comment: Well, I wasn't completely lost, I can see now what I did wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I am not good at writing nested loops in one line. But this will remove duplicates and creates a 3D list with pairs:

```
mylist = [[[3, 2, 4, 3], [3, 2, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [3, 1], [2, 1]]]
res = []

for inner in mylist:
    temp = []
    for each in inner:
        for e in zip(each, each[1:]):
            if list(e) not in temp:
                temp.append(list(e))
    res.append(temp)

print(res)  # [[[3, 2], [2, 4], [4, 3], [2, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [2, 1]]]
```

Comment: Thank you! With this I think I can remove duplicate using list comprehension, I can get some ideas